# It´s possible to use a wildcard SSL certificate in SFTP/SSH connection?

Tags: ssl, certificate, sftp, wildcard, private

I have a wildcard SSL certificate, *.mydomain.com, private, public Keys, pem/key file, certificate, etc.

I have a SFTP/SSH Server based on MySecureShell to share and get some data using FTPS with outsourced biz partners

It´s possible to configure SFTP Server to send the SSL wildcard certificate as key, insted the default one? I´m not talking about identify USERS using certificates, but users with standard passwords but protected with the SSL wildcard certificate, the idea here is manly target to make SFTP users to connect using sftp.mydomain.com without poping-up alerts

Comment: When you buy a certification, You can choose wildcard and it's more expensive related to normal certification.

Answer (score 4):

no. SSH/SFTP is not using SSL certificates, but SSH certificates or keys (unless you have specially crated [SSH server and clients supporting this](http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/)).

But you can configure this way FTPs server for sharing your data.

Or you can store the SSH fingerprints to SSHFP DNS records to avoid prompt on the side of users (also depends on the client software, if it implements this possibility).